# FLUTTER: Deployment on ARM64 based Board

Tags: linux, flutter, x86-64, arm64, cross-build

Hello and thank you for stopping by!

So far the experience has been great on my dev. laptop (Linux AMD64) but the apps that I want to develop are targeted mostly for ARM64 based Linux one PCB computers.
First I tried cross-compiling from the laptop with the target set as ARM64 and I got an error stating that this feature (cross-compiling from AMD64 for ARM64) is not currently supported. I tried installing Flutter SDK manually and configuring VSCode on the ARM64 board (OrangePI4LTS-ArmbianOS) and everything seemed to work until I tried running an app. I built a demo app using the create new flutter project from command palette and trying to run it (either debug or release mode) greeted me with this error:

```
eos@orangepi4-lts:~/VSsandbox/my_app$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
Building Linux application...

(my_app:4163): Gdk-ERROR **: 12:35:04.021: The program 'my_app' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'GLXBadFBConfig'.
(Details: serial 252 error_code 167 request_code 152 (GLX) minor_code 0)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Which, I can say from my limited knowledge, it maybe links to some hardware capability problem.
Can you please help me determine whether if there is a way to make this work or not? In my opinion OrangePI4 is a rather capable board so it seems more likely that I'm doing something wrong/I'm unaware of something rather than having no workaround for this due to hardware limitation (at least the example app). Also It is OpenGL 3.2 capable if it is relevant.
Thank you very much for your time.